# Scatter plot with Y axis labels like Gantt chart

Tags: visualization

Here is a Gantt chart visualization by Amcharts, from https://www.amcharts.com/demos/gantt-chart-dates/ :
[image: amcharts gantt chart]

I want this same kind of viz, but with dots/circles for timestamp based data points instead of duration bands. How to go about it? I'm open to using other libraries or rolling my own code. This could be called a scatter plot, but the Y-axis is vertically spaced labels/categories like in this Gantt chart instead of numeric.

Bigger picture, might help narrow down search: Mainly looking for a way to visualize multiple categories of events which have their own timestamps and values in a combined viz. The Gantt chart viz does a terrific job for duration-based events. Vertically separating the categories is critical - each should have its own lane.